# Spectacle ReactJS can't access my own store state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, spectacle

I'm using
[Spectacle](http://formidable.com/open-source/spectacle/) to create a slideshow web app, but I am having some trouble accessing my own redux store while inside the `<Deck>` Component (from spectacle)

What I mean is I can access my own ReduxStore within my whole application, but for those component that are inside `<Deck>` when I try to access store, I end up accessing Spectacle-Redux
e.g

```
<Deck>
    <Slide>
        <MyComponent />
    </Slide>
</Deck>
```

In MyComponent I can't access my redux-store, instead I access Spectacle's one.

Is there a way to access my own redux inside `<Deck />`?

Comment: you can use context API

Comment: @HajjiTarik yea, I end up doing exactly this. thanks!